# ORDER BY upper(...) with a UNION giving me problems

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, union-all

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why I'm having this problem.

This code works exactly how it should. It combines the two tables (MESSAGES and MESSAGES_ARCHIVE) and orders them correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT rownum as rn, a.* FROM ( 
        SELECT  
        outbound.FROM_ADDR, outbound.TO_ADDR, outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT

        from MESSAGES outbound 
        where (1 = 1) 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
        outboundarch.FROM_ADDR, outboundarch.TO_ADDR, outboundarch.EMAIL_SUBJECT

        from MESSAGES_ARCHIVE outboundarch 
        where (1 = 1)  

        order by FROM_ADDR DESC 
    ) a 
) where rn between 1 and 25
```

However, this code does not work.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT rownum as rn, a.* FROM ( 
        SELECT  
        outbound.FROM_ADDR, outbound.TO_ADDR, outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT

        from MESSAGES outbound 
        where (1 = 1) 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
        outboundarch.FROM_ADDR, outboundarch.TO_ADDR, outboundarch.EMAIL_SUBJECT

        from MESSAGES_ARCHIVE outboundarch 
        where (1 = 1)  

        order by upper(FROM_ADDR) DESC 
    ) a 
) where rn between 1 and 25
```

and returns this error

```
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
01785. 00000 -  "ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression"
```

I'm trying to get the two tables ordered regardless of letter case, which is why I'm using `upper(FROM_ADDR)`.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: With UNIONS(ALL) and DISTINCT , ORDER by should be specified with the exact selected expression or mentioned as 1,2.. as column position. In general I would believe, Order by something not in SELECT, oracle implicitly includes in select and order it.. In this case, oracle, could _not_ add the UPPER() implicitly just bevauce, it has to work on the SET operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this is generating an error, but it probably has to do with scoping rules for `union` queries.  There is an easy work-around, using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT row_number() over (order by upper(FROM_ADDR)) as rn, a.*
    FROM ( 
        SELECT  
        outbound.FROM_ADDR, outbound.TO_ADDR, outbound.EMAIL_SUBJECT

        from MESSAGES outbound 
        where (1 = 1) 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
        outboundarch.FROM_ADDR, outboundarch.TO_ADDR, outboundarch.EMAIL_SUBJECT

        from MESSAGES_ARCHIVE outboundarch 
        where (1 = 1)  

    ) a 
)
where rn between 1 and 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Your upper() is returning a value, but not a column name.
Instead of:

```
order by upper(FROM_ADDR) DESC
```

try:

```
order by upper(FROM_ADDR) as FROM_ADDR DESC
```